# I changed my minecraft username and nothing works

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently changed my Minecraft username through [mojang](https://mojang.com/), and everything was good. Then I opened minecraft from my desktop to mineplex, and this showed up:

> Not authenticated with minecraft.net

Please help. I already tried restarting my minecraft, refreshing, and logging out and in.

Comment: Do other servers work?

Comment: Did you try logging out(click the logout button) and loggin in again in the launcher? Im not sure, but the name change may have invalidated the login key, your client stored for login.

Answer (score 1):

Log out of minecraft completely

[image]

If this doesn't work try deleting .minecraft and completely reinstalling Minecraft (I suggest first making a backup of servers.dat, saves and resource packs)