# I am not authenticated on minecraft.net!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Basically, I changed my display name in launcher_profiles.json and then
when I tried to play on a server it says not authenticated to minecraft.net can somebody help me!

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250128/i-changed-my-minecraft-username-and-nothing-works)

Comment: How about changing it back

Answer (score 1):

Fix: Change your name back!

You should not be changing your name in the launcher_profiles.json. Ever.

If you want to change your name  do this:

1. Go to [Minecraft's official website](https://minecraft.net/)
2. Log in with your **original** name (The one you had **before** you changed it)
3. Next to your name click on **change**
4. Put in your new name, and then your password underneath
5. Press change!

This will change your name to the new name that you want to use :D

**Edit:**

If you have followed the steps above and your name does not change, log in and out of the Minecraft Launcher. It may take some time to process the change